# send command line to a linux server with php

Tags: php, linux, command-line

I've set a linux (ubuntu serv) as a RMTP server using nginx , and i'd like to be able to restart the service from a web interface as it does crashes from time to time.

I was thinking php would be great to send command line to linux , but the only way i found is to use exec()and give root permissions to www-data which doesn not sound like a good idea.

I also dont want to restart the server by itself , only the rmtp service (other stuffs running on this server)

so to sum up , i'd like to be able to send command line to a linux on a web interface w/e the language/technology is used

thanks guys and sorry for my bad english

Comment: `sudo`: `<?php exec('sudo service restart name_of_service_here'); ?>` basically.

Comment: unless i give permissions to www-data this wont work , and this doesnt sounds good to do so as that creates a huge security issue

Comment: regardless of HOW you do it, you're wanting to trigger an action via http that REQUIRES root access. This is just one way of doing it.

Comment: You could have php touch a file on the server, for example restart.txt, then have a root cron script to check for the existence of the file and delete it and restart the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to reinvent the wheel. There are tools out there for monitoring services. They will restart them if needed.

Take a look at

monit
http://mmonit.com/monit/

and

supervisord
http://supervisord.org/